# outer variable from nested loop

Tags: php, arrays, variables, for-loop

At the moment, i have:

```
$lines = ['0747890304', '0748906475', '0749104331', '0741233114'];
$inputs = ['074589', '074789', '074910'];
$output = [];

foreach($lines as $keyLine => $line){
    foreach($inputs as $inputLine => $input){
        if(strpos($line, $input) !== false){
            $output[] = $line;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($output); // i got only the last loop. Variable gets overriden
```

And I want a list of `$lines` that contains and start with `$inputs`. I'm stuck.

Comment: "Notice: Undefined variable: var_dump in" which gives a clue that your shared code is not your actual code. Which explains the no repro: https://3v4l.org/O0NbX

Comment: `$var_dump`? You're using a variable function.

Comment: foreach($lines as $keyLine => $line) should be foreach($lines as $line)

Comment: i need that variable from inside the loop to export it in a file

Comment: How is that going to make a difference @AammadUllah?

Comment: And foreach($inputs as $inputLine => $input)  should be   foreach($inputs as $input)

Comment: @AammadUllah that part doesn't influence the outcome

Comment: Again (or rather still...) @AammadUllah what are you on about? How is that in any way going to make a difference?

Comment: yes, first, i tried without giveing a key, but i thought that will work with a key, but not :(

Comment: Your `strpos()` test just checks whether `$line` contains `$input`, it doesn't check whether it starts with it. You should use `=== 0`, not `!== false`.

Comment: yes, you are right @Barmar but even like this, my $output variable gets overriden with the last loop values. That's the big problem. Thank you

Comment: @Spidey That would only happen if you wrote `$output =` instead of `$output[] =`.

Comment: If that's the big problem, why doesn't the question say so?

Comment: That's the title, about the variable that i cannot use it with all the values outside the loop. sorry if i was missunderstood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This Loop of yours functions as it should. [Quick-Test Here.](https://eval.in/666256)

```
    $lines  = ['0747890304', '0748906475', '0749104331', '0741233114'];
    $inputs = ['074589', '074789', '074910'];
    $output = [];

    foreach($lines as $keyLine => $line){
        foreach($inputs as $inputLine => $input){
            if(strpos($line, $input) !== false){
                $output[] = $line;
            }
        }
    }
    var_dump($output);
    // YIELDS::
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '0747890304' (length=10)
      1 => string '0749104331' (length=10)
```

Comment: also @PeeHaa gave the same answer, so thank you both. Seems that with fixed array values works, but i read the values from file, i get an array exactly like this, but doesn't work. I get only one value from last loops, like the variables gets overriden. i don't know why, but your version works si i have to accept the answer. Thank you